# Can I split the feed to a duplex 20 amp receptacle from different capacity circuits?

Tags: wiring, receptacle

Is it possible to split-feed a 20 Amp receptacle with one receptacle using 15amp and the other 20amp circuits?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  We need more details and need to understand the problem you are solving.

Comment: Smells like an XY-problem. What are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 3):

<s>No, you can't feed a split receptacle from circuits with differently-sized breakers. Here's why:</s>

You can, but you have to meet certain conditions:

> The National Electrical Code now requires that the two hot wires in a split receptacle must be connected to a double-pole circuit breaker, so that when the breaker is shut off, the action will automatically disconnect both receptacles. That way, the outlet will be safe to work on.
>
> <sub>[source: The Spruce](https://www.thespruce.com/split-outlet-warnings-and-rules-1152798)</sub>

To my knowledge, handle-tied double breakers with different current ratings don't exist. However, as [ThreePhaseEeel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/27099/threephaseeel) points out, you may be able to find UL listed handle-ties for your breaker brand. This would require that they be mounted adjacent. Or you could reduce the 20A circuit to 15 Amps and use the same wire.

Comment: You could use a 15A and a 20A single pole with a handle tie connecting the two...

Answer (score 3):

### I'll be darned.  You can do it.

The crux of the issue is supplying a 20A NEMA 5-20 receptacle (T-shaped neutral) on a 15A breaker.

Since you will only have one socket on the entire circuit, this applies.

> **210.21(B)(1) Single Receptacle on an Individual Branch Circuit.** A single receptacle installed on an individual branch circuit shall have an ampere rating not less than that of the branch circuit.

So a solitary socket on a 15A circuit must be at least 15A.

### What if the circuit had more than one socket?

However, if this 20A circuit supplied other receptacles, then you wouldn't have a solitary outlet. Table 210.21(B)(3) would apply, and 15A receptacles would be allowed on a 20A circuit -- *but 20A receptacles would not be allowed on a 15A circuit*.

[image]

### How do you breaker this thing?

Because you have a single *yoke* with two separate circuits on it, **the circuits must have common maintenance shutoff**.  Having two breakers with different values can be accomplished by using individual 1-pole breakers and **identified (listed) handle ties**.

Answer (score 1):

Isherwood raises the most relevant point I think, but another issue is that you would only be able to use an outlet (with the tabs removed) with maximum 15A rating.  This pretty much negates any advantage of having a 20A circuit (presumably with 12G wire run) anyway.